# how to hyperlink from a normal text to a bulleted text?

Tags: xml

Explanation of the question-

In the given bulleted list, I want a hyperlink pointing to bullet 3 from a normal text,

```
<ol>
<li> Set the value to zero</li>
<li> Update the zig file</li>
<li id="aeiou5"> Run the script</li>
</ol>

<p>If you get any error update the die file and redo step 3. </p>
```

In the above text I want 'step 3' to be a hyperlink pointing to 3rd bulleted list.
I wrote this XML code, `<xref href="procedure.xml#aeiou5"/>`
 where procedure`is the name of the file and`aeiou5` is the id of 3rd bullet. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your `<li>` tags correctly.

Use `<li id="desiredId">Text to display</li>`

Edit:
I see you edited your OP.

You can link to id's by using `<a href="#aeiou5">step 3</a>`. It then will jump to the element with the matching id.

Comment: actually iwrote it wrong here by mistake, i have corrected it

Comment: if you see the code now, it is correct syntax wise but still its not linking.